# Laravel 4 - Find Method Gets All Data

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-4, orm, eloquent

I don't know why or how to fix this but whenever I'm using Profile::find($id) it returns all data and not the item I want.

I can't find a reason why this would be the case.

Model

```
class Profile extends Eloquent 
{
    public static $rules = array(
        'first_name'        => array('required', 'alpha', 'min:3'),
        'last_name'         => array('required', 'alpha', 'min:3'),
        'date_of_birth'     => array('date'),
        'telephone'         => array('digits'),
        'gender'            => array('required', 'alpha', 'in:Male,Female')
    );

    protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth', 'gender'];

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function user() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function attributes() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Attribute', 'profile_attributes', 'profile_id', 'attribute_id')
                    ->withPivot('attribute_value_id');
    }

    public function values() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('AttributeValue', 'profile_attributes', 'profile_id', 'attribute_value_id')
                    ->withPivot('attribute_id');
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public function show($id) 
{
    $data['profile'] = Profile::find(11)->get()->toArray();
    return View::make('profile.show', $data);
}
```

Result

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=14)
      'id' => int 10
      'user_id' => int 1
      'first_name' => string 'Richard' (length=7)
      'last_name' => string 'Skinner' (length=7)
      'date_of_birth' => string '1980-01-01' (length=10)
      'bio' => string 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis tempor pellentesque bibendum. Vestibulum congue est non imperdiet varius. Morbi a nunc nec nulla euismod sodales. Morbi id maximus sem. Proin tempor molestie feugiat. Ut pharetra felis quis erat sagittis volutpat. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris fermentum vitae nisi vel varius. Proin sagittis varius placerat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;

Donec tinci'... (length=2043)
      'telephone' => null
      'gender' => string 'male' (length=4)
      'profile_picture' => string 'IMG_0005.JPG' (length=12)
      'latitude' => null
      'longitude' => null
      'created_at' => string '2015-05-02 16:35:51' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2015-05-20 18:52:51' (length=19)
      'deleted_at' => null
  1 => 
    array (size=14)
      'id' => int 11
      'user_id' => int 2
      'first_name' => string 'Sydney' (length=6)
      'last_name' => string 'Nouch' (length=5)
      'date_of_birth' => string '0000-00-00' (length=10)
      'bio' => string 'I need a bio' (length=12)
      'telephone' => null
      'gender' => string 'female' (length=6)
      'profile_picture' => string 'Sunflower.gif' (length=13)
      'latitude' => null
      'longitude' => null
      'created_at' => string '2015-07-21 18:01:22' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2015-07-21 18:14:30' (length=19)
      'deleted_at' => null
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you paste the code where you call Profile::find()? There is no way this method could return more than one result if single primary key value is passed as an argument

Comment: Agreed, there's not enough code given to find the problem. Can you post an example of what `Profile::find($id)` is returning? Or at least what object type it's returning?

Comment: @Ben Fair enough, I've just completed the rest of what happening. I know there is no way - or shouldn't be no way - the method returns no more than the ID but for some reason it is doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i've found the answer but not sure why the behaviour happens. But here goes...

When using find you can call the

> toArray

method which will get only the result required.

This is what I don't understand maybe some can clarify why. When you call the

> get

method it gets all the data from the model, thats what i was doing wrong.

So my final piece of code was as follows

> $data['profile'] = Profile::with('attributes')->find($id)->toArray();

Hope that helps someone not to waste a day.